# Players don't want to play with each other

Tags: problem-players

I am a Dungeon Master for a group, and a new guy comes in and constantly talks over the other players (me included), and the other players want to bully him out of the game/group, I tried asking him to find another group in the store to avoid drama, but he now comes to spite the other players, I'm in a mess of a pickle, should I just disband the group? let the players sort this out? What should I do?

Comment: If the whole group wants him out, how is this a problem? Just, as a group, tell him that he's not welcome to play with you.

Comment: The mention of a store makes me wonder if the store won't let you tell the player he isn't welcome.  Is that the case?

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear until we can find out why "disinvite him from the group" isn't a viable solution. If it *could* be viable but you're just not sure how to go about it, please let us know what the problem might be. You may want to check [How can I politely ask a player to leave my game?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30541/1204), and make sure you're not falling prey to [Geek Social Fallacy #1: "ostracizers are evil"](http://www.plausiblydeniable.com/opinion/gsf.html).

Comment: Is there a reason that the game can't be played at another location?  (Like your place, or the place where one of your players lives?)